# Android turn off screen without restarting game

Tags: android, screen

I'm trying to create an android game, but having problem with turning off screen.

Currently my game works like so that when i press home button it pauses and when you press back button it stops and later starts again.

Now i noticed that when i press power button to turn off screen it stops the game, without closing, and when i turn screen back on its restarted.
I would like to prevent that and make the game only pause when i turn off screen,

My current code:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (!mGameIsRunning) {
        mGameIsRunning = true;
        loop = new GameLoop(getHolder(), this);
        createSprites();
        loop.setRunning(true);
        loop.start();

    } else {
        resume();
    }

}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    pause();
}

public void pause() {
    loop.setRunning(false);
    while (true) {
        try {
            loop.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        break;
    }
    loop = null;
}

public void resume() {
    loop = new GameLoop(getHolder(), this);
    loop.setRunning(true);
    loop.start();
}
```

Comment: Noone knows any other sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your application is losing its OpenGL context and has to restart when you re-open it. As I remember it, the context will be saved for some time if you use the 'home' button, but it is dropped when you use either the back button or put the device to sleep.

You could try to use the 'home' button and leave it in the background for some time, your tests probably were like this: 'home' button -> instantly switch back *works*. Try to give it some time for the context to drop.

Again, I'm not sure. It has been a while for me since I have done any Android programming.

Comment: No, I left it for a few minutes and it still worked, but will try to leave it longer. Still thanks for help